# On Groupie Recycler view every 7 rows it repeats the same uid of firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I dont know what to do in this case because every 7 rows the image drawable is favorite even when it shouldn't be.

```
class RecipesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes)

getRecipes()        
    }
    companion object{
        val REC_KEY = "REC_KEY"
    }
    var adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
    private fun getRecipes(){
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/recipes")
        val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                p0.children.forEach{
                    val reci = it.getValue(Recipes::class.java)
                    if(reci != null) {
                        adapter.add(RecipesItem(reci))
                    }
                }
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener{ item, view ->
                    val recItem = item as RecipesItem
                    val intent = Intent(view.context, RecipeDetail::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(REC_KEY, recItem.recipes)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                recycler_recipes.adapter = adapter
            }
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This class is to put the items in the views. I need them to be, but when I check for favourite or not there's the problem.

```
class RecipesItem(val recipes: Recipes): Item<GroupieViewHolder>(){
    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.name_recycler.text = recipes.reci_name
        viewHolder.itemView.type_recipes.text = recipes.reci_diet
        viewHolder.itemView.timeToPrepare.text = recipes.reci_time.plus(" min")

        //checkiffav
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val fav = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$user/fav_recipes/${recipes.id}")
        fav.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot){
                if(p0.exists()){
                    viewHolder.itemView.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite)
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.row_recipes
    }
    }
```

Basically I have 20 recipes and I have a favorite system, but the recycler view only gets the id of the recipes on every 7 rows, then it repeats the same id's! I'm really new to kotlin and firebase and I dont know how to solve. On every 7 rows the recipe appears has fav because the id that the firebase reference is getting is the same as the first one.

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Comment: @yalpsideman basically i have 20 recipes and i have a favorite system, but the recycler view only gets the id of the recipes on every 7 rows than it repeats the same id's! im really new to kotlin and firebase and i dont know how to solve. On every 7 rows the recipe appears has fav because the id that the firebase reference is getting is the same as the first one

Answer (score 0):

Answered on Groupie issue tracker: https://github.com/lisawray/groupie/issues/320#issuecomment-581915693